# PHP code is displayed in my form field

Tags: php

Is this correct if I'm trying to get a date value inside an input box?
When running the page, I get `<?=$todate?>` inside the box instead of the actual date.

```
$todate=$_REQUEST['todate'];
```

That is how I am requesting the `$todate` variable.

Comment: Have you tried without using the PHP short tags? Not all servers support them - try `<?php echo $todate ?>` instead

Comment: It's generally best practice to not use short tags.

Comment: since some host do not support shorttags.

Answer (score 2):

Either turn on short tags in your php.ini file, or convert your code to `<?php echo $var;?>`... and make sure your page is being parsed as PHP

Comment: O: = {Ahhh! Short tags}... Good solution though with the full tags. +1

Comment: Thank you, short tags wasn't enabled in php.ini.

Answer (score 0):

Set

```
short_open_tag = on
```

in `php.ini` and restart your web server.

Answer (score 0):

I guess you embedded PHP in an .html file. Copy your code into a .php file (e.g. test.php), start your webserver (e.g. apache in xampp) and call your script via URL in browser:

```
http://localhost/test.php?todate=12.02.1980
```

PHP-Code:

```
<?php 
    if(isset($_REQUEST['todate'])) 
        $todate = $_REQUEST['todate'];
    else
        $todate = null;
?>
```

HTML:

```
<form name="myForm">
    <input type="text" value="<?=$todate; ?>"> 
</form>
```